# Packages distributed in the github registry cannot be installed

Tags: npm, npm-install, github-package-registry

I created and published package which depends on the typeorm package, to the github registry.

The deployment was successful, but when I try install the package, I got a message:

```
“Package not found.” cause npm try to  install my package's dependency from "npm.pkg.github.com".
```

I want to allow only dependent packages to be installed from registry.npmjs.com. What should I do?

I tried this command,

```
 npm install @narumir/my-package@0.0.1 --registry https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

and I got this error.

[image: install package error]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the registry in your package.json file or in your npm configuration.

```
{
  "name": "your-package-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "typeorm": "version",
    // Other dependencies
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://registry.npmjs.com/"
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can set the registry globally using npm CLI:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.com/
```

Comment: I tried this command 
```
 npm install @narumir/my-package@0.0.1 --registry https://npm.pkg.github.com 
```
and got error message "not found" @narumir/my-package has typeorm dependenies. i don't want to deploy my package to npmjs.